# React Router Issue (delay changing the route on click) using v 5.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Im running into an issue where when I click on a Link  in my nav bar, the url can lag behind, making me sometimes have to click twice to finally get the url to change.

the Link path was originally based on state passed through props which I though might be the issue, but at this point I've hard coded the paths and I'm still running into problems.

example:

```
<Link to={"/ugh"}>{HeaderItem.link}</Link>
```

Are there some common gotcha's with React Router that I might be missing here? Or a bug in the 5.2.0 version?

Comment: Are you using some framework like Nextjs or Gatsby?

Comment: Are you using anything for page transitions such as framer-motion? If there are typos within animations it will lag (especially with framer-motion) as it tries to execute those typos. I would also try `to="/ugh"`, no braces.

Comment: Hmm, I am using animations, with React-scroll, but its not being used in the routes Im calling. 

Do you think that could be it? 

Also I tried the no braces, still the same issue.

Comment: @iunfixit Im just using regular ol react

Comment: Can you check if it happens when you build and serve it with `npm run build` and `serve -s build`, serve needs to be installed https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ so we can rule out it being just a development issue

Comment: Still the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Stupidly easy solution for a problem staring me right in the face.

My Link tag wasnt wrapping the whole div, making some areas non responsive to the click.

Big oof.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.